# PWA redirects to login page and stuck in 2FA loop

Tags: ios, safari, react-redux, azure-active-directory, progressive-web-apps

I am working on PWA app using React-Redux. Using Adal for azure login. 2 factor authentication is enabled for the user.

Problem is on iOS when the user gets the Pin for 2 FA and switches away from app to see the pin in the messaging app and comes back to PWA app, PWA refreshes and takes the user to login page.

I have searched everywhere and could not find any answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 12.2 was just released 2 days agao and it fixed the problem:

PWAs (Progressive Web App) have a new lifecycle and on most normal situations, the state of your app will be saved and restored between sessions.

A link to an external site opens in a “PWA In-App browser” instead of Safari and if the external site links to the PWA’s scope again, the navigation goes back to the PWA. Now we can log in users on external origins within a PWA (such as with OAuth). Credit to [Medium article](https://medium.com/@firt/whats-new-on-ios-12-2-for-progressive-web-apps-75c348f8e945)

Answer (score 0):

Try maintaining state using IndexedDB. This will work with a PWA on iOS Safari. Another advantage of using indexedDB is that pages on the same domain that live outside of the PWA can write to IndexedDB and that data can be read, any encryption signature verified, and used by the PWA, which also has access to IndexedDB.